# Can I create a common include file in HTML?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am just wondering if this is possible. I have almost 50 html files in my project and have almost common include files like bootstrap, angular, jquery ui etc.

Can I write a common file say include.html that is similar to say `import java.util.*`. my include.html will contain 3-4 entries of my common JS and CSS files and then I can include that file in my each html page?

like say user.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
import include.html (or any other appropriate name or file format)
</head>....
```

I do not want common header and footer files I want to include required files in one shot by including one html file.

Comment: You really need a basic server side script like PHP for that to do. PHP being the basic one as it doesn't need much setting up.

Comment: you could fetch them with an AJAX GET call. But if the user doesn't have scripts enabled, they will lose that content

Comment: so it is not possible in pure html / JS, right?

Comment: @JacobGray Not possible for including JS / CSS file. Do you understand what he's asking?

Comment: @user1079065 No way. Sorry. `:(` HTML will soon become powerful.

Comment: I guess Angular makes it possible to have such structure... `:P`

Comment: @PraveenKumar Can't you just send a get request like http://jsfiddle.net/jacobgray/ye5cz13n/

Comment: @JacobGray For `<!DOCTYPE html>`???

Comment: Well, it works anyway

Comment: No way buddy... I am saying like, header and footer using PHP or something. Including the basic script tag... Do you get it? `:(` This shit happens, when you wanna do a template or design.

Comment: Oh, gotcha. But the OP never said it had PHP in it.

Comment: LoL... Where's PHP? Check this out BTW: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Side_Includes

Comment: You could use Jekyll or a static site generator, technically.